# Background image above a border

Tags: html, css

I would like to make this textbox

[image]

As you can see, there are two parts to the div - the background image in the bottom and the border, that I have already done:

HTML:

```
<div class="person">
<p>Text Text Text</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.person {
    background: url('../images/results_title.png') repeat-x bottom;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    min-height: 32px;
}
```

The problem is that the border is above the background image. The background in the bottom should be above the border (= in the bottom should be just an image without any borders).

IMPORTANT:
There is a text on the image.

Comment: can you add the border to your image then you don't have to use css to create it?  Or instead of `border: 1px solid #000000;` call out which borders you want to set as 1px `border-right: 1px solid #000000;`, `border-left: 1px solid #000000;` and `border-top: 1px solid #000000;`

Comment: border left and right are above the image in the sides, that the problem.

Comment: then just remove the `border: 1px solid #000000;` altogether.

Answer (score 0):

how about adding the border to the `<p>`? You can have a border-right and border-left on the p, with inside padding to keep the text away from the box. If the `<p>`'s have other layout that would hinder this, wrap them in a div.

See this fiddle, for example:
http://jsfiddle.net/56TqY/1/

The red and cyan are just to examplify, and obviously I use your background with the text, but I think you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

I always hate adding more markup, but I think [this](http://jsfiddle.net/uaxpN/) should be what you're looking for.

I just added a wrapper so that you can add a padding between the `border` and the `background-image`